# Controlling http streams with python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, http, pycurl, python-multithreading

I am implementing an app consuming a few http streams at the same time.
All threads (a pycurl object each) are spawned in the same loop.
The trick is how to build a proper architecture for handling reconnects.

Is it a good practice to create a separate controller thread that somehow
checks which connections are not alive or need forced reconnect?

Or may be such task should be done inside separate processes?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have one controling thread which spawns http streaming threads, and such a streaming thread implements the proper handling for a connection loss or timeout (e.g. either terminating itself or telling to controling thread that a new streaming thread should be spawned for a reconnect). Depending on your http serving peer you could also try to continue an interrupted stream by using the http Content-Range feature.